# Dropdown menu that does not work properly

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, dropdown

On my Website, I have a menu bar that has some direct links and two dropdown menus.

On the mobile phone, when I first tape on THE SECONDE DROPDOWN MENU, it open and I can see its links. Then, I tape on the FIRST DROPDOWN MENU witch it open find also. But, now, when I tape back on the SECOND DROPDOWN MENU, it acts as if I had taped the next direct link of the menu bar.

I tried to put a death link (#) on, for instance, the second dropdown menu with no success.

If you want to check : https://www.veganimaliste.com/index.php

Here is the PHP HTML CODE

```
<!-- ANCHOR BACK TO THE TOP --> 
<span id="haut-page" class="anchor"></span>
<!-- ANCHOR BACK TO THE TOP END-->

<!-- LOGO AND MENU WRAPP -->
<div class="menu-wrap">

    <!-- WEBSITE LOGO -->
    <div class="logo"><a href="index.php" target="_self"><span class="logo-line"><span class="logo-color">veg</span>animaliste</span>.com</a> </div>
    <!-- WEBSITE LOGO END-->

    <!-- MENU -->
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">

        <!-- FIRST DIRECT MENU LINK / HOME PAGE-->
        <a href="index.php" title="Page d'accueil" target="_self"><img class="sans-texte" src="img/menu/home-g.png" ></a>
        <!-- FIRST DIRECT MENU LINK / HOME PAGE END -->

        <!-- FIRST DROPDOWN MENU -->
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">VÉGANISME <img src="img/menu/down-g.png"/></button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="v-intro.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Vérités ugentes à connaître</a>
                <a href="articles.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Articles</a>
                <a href="reponses.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Réponses aux non-véganes</a>
                <a href="reponses-av.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Réponses de AV aux non-véganes</a>
                <a href="qui-sont-ils.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Qui sont-ils? </a>
                <a href="ce-que-nous-pouvons-faire.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Ce que nous pouvons faire</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- DROPDOWN MENU END -->

        <!-- SECONDE DROPDOWN MENU -->
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">DOCUMENTS <img src="img/menu/down-g.png"/></button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="videos.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Vidéos</a>
                <a href="defenitions.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Défénitions</a>
                <a href="sites.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Sites recommandés</a>
                <a href="livres.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Livres recommandés</a>
                <a href="ressources.php" target="_self"><img src="img/menu/dot-g.png"/>Ressources</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- SECONDE DROPDOWN MENU END-->

        <!-- OTHER DIRECT MENU LINK -->
        <a href="recherche.php" title="Rechercher sur le site" target="_self"><img class="sans-texte" src="img/menu/recherche.png"/></a>
        <a href="a-propos.php" title="À propos" target="_self"><img class="sans-texte" src="img/menu/a-propos-g.png"/></a>
        <a href="contact.php" title="M'écrire" target="_self"><img class="sans-texte" src="img/menu/enveloppe-g.png"/></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/renedemoors" title="Me joindre sur Facobook" target="_blank"><img class="sans-texte" src="img/partage/facebook-s.png"/></a>
        <!-- OTHER DIRECT MENU LINK END -->

        <!-- DIRECT LINK TO CHANGE LANGUAGE -->
                                

<a href="   <?php 

$url= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 

$positionslash= strrpos($url, "/");

$filename= substr($url, $positionslash + 1);

echo "en/". $filename;

?>  " title="english" target="_self"><span class="menu-lang">English</span></a>
        <!-- DIRECT LINK TO CHANGE LANGUAGE END -->

        <!-- OPEN / CLOSE MOBILE MENU -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><img src="img/menu/bars-g.png" alt="menu"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
            <div class="menu-open"><img src="img/menu/bars-g.png" alt="menu"/>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-close"><img src="img/menu/times-r.png" alt="fermer"/>
            </div>
        </a>
        <!-- OPEN / CLOSE MOBILE MENU END -->
    </div>
    <!-- MENU END -->
</div>
<!-- LOGO AND MENU WRAPP END -->
```

Here is the CSS CODE

```
/* LOGO */
.logo {
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 27px;
    height: 73px;
    background-color: black;
}
.logo a {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 18px 5px 25px 5px;
    letter-spacing: -.5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 lightgreen;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
/*  color of the letters Veg of the logo */
.logo .logo-color {
    color: lightgreen;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.logo .logo-color-2 {
    color: dimgray;
    margin-right: 0;
}
/* LOGO END */

/* MENUM */
.menu-lang {
    color: lightgreen;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-style: italic;
}
.menu-wrap.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    /*d'autres proprietes si besoin*/
}
.menu-wrap {
    font-style: normal;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 200;
    height: 73px;
    background-color: black;
}
.topnav {
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 32px 0 0;
    height: 73px;
    background: black;
    letter-spacing: -1.5px;
} 
/* direct linksof the menu */
.topnav a {
    color: white;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 10px 19px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 21px;
}

/*  menu icons */
.topnav img {
    height: 14px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 4px 0 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* direct links icons */
img.sans-texte {
    height: 22px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 4px 0 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* images icones dans le texte---------------------*/
img.sans-texte-2 {
    height: 35px;
    width: auto;
    background: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
img.sans-texte-2:hover {
    transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.topnav .icon {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: lightgreen;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: none;
}

/* DROPDOWN MENU */
/* left aligment of dropdown menu links */
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* dropdown menu links */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 21px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 28px 2px 20px 5px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
}
/* dropdwon menu contant */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
/* dropdown menu links */
.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: lightgreen;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding: 15px 35px 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
/* bottom line of dropdown menu liks*/
.dropdown-content a {
    border-top: 1px solid #4B4A4A;
}
/* hover on dropdwown menu links */
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    color: white;
}
/* meme chose */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    color: white;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* MEDIA QUERY */
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    /* ----- disparitoin du menu horizontal  --- */
    .topnav a, .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: none;
        background: black;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    /*show vertical menu open button */
    .topnav a.icon {
        position: absolute;
        float: right;
        display: block;
        top: 0;
        margin: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: 26px 25px 16px 22px;
        border: none;
    }
    /* hover / vertical menu close button */
    .topnav a.icon:hover {
        background: black;
        border: none;
    }

    /* ----------- menu ----------------*/
    /*every links with or without dropdown links*/
    .topnav.responsive {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: black;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 204;
        letter-spacing: normal;     
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
    }
    /* dropdown menu */
    .topnav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        float: right;
        display: block;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        width: 72px;
        height: 72px;
    }
    /* dropdown menu */
    .topnav.responsive a {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 35px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #4B4A4A;
    }
    /* make the menu vertical */
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
        float: none;
    }

    /* dropdown menu */
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    /* show dropdowm menu links*/
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 35px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #4B4A4A;
        letter-spacing: normal;
    }
}
/* show open button of the vertical menu*/
.topnav .menu-open {
    display: block;
}
/* hide vertical menu close button */
.topnav .menu-close {
    display: none;
}
/* hide vertical menu open button*/
.topnav.responsive .menu-open {
    display: none;
}
/* vertical menu close button */
.topnav.responsive .menu-close {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 26px 25px 16px 22px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .logo a {
        font-size: 95%;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 lightgreen;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are add only hover to show sub menus in css. Please add 'active' class to menu item when clicked the menu using jquery.

```css
.dropdown.active .dropdown-content {
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rayess, I'm answering to your suggestion here because I can't make the code look good when I use Add Comment.

The only other js code I use is this

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

Is your suggestion will work and how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I add  this **display:block;** to the code below. So, now, all the dropdown menus stay open witch is better but I'd rather like we could open and close them by taping on their title. I don't know how to use js.

```
/* dropdown menu */
.topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    display:block; /* keep open all the dropdown menus*/
}
```